# No termina el juego a los 10 segundos flappy bird

Tags: unity

No sé por que no termina el juego a los 10 segundos, es por que no tengo cargada una nueva escena? o no tengo nada puesto para que cuando pase esos 10 segundos haga algo?. Deberia de poner una escena para que cuando pase esos 10 segundos cargue esa escena ?

en esta linea de codigo:

```
  private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            ///
            /// aqui poner el codigo para mostrar que gano
            ///
        }
```

**Este es el codigo de bird:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Timers;
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {
    // Movement speed
    public float speed = 1;


    // Flap force
    public float force = 100;

    public double Interval = 10000;

    private Timer t;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
      // Fly towards the right
      GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
      t = new Timer(Interval);
      t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
      t.Start();
  }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Flap
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * force);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // Restart
        t.Stop();
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

    private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            ///
            /// aqui poner el codigo para mostrar que gano
            ///
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente, no soy un gran developer de Unity, pero desde lo que yo entiendo, no veo nada que compruebe que cuando a los 10 segundos se cambie de escena.

En primer lugar, donde mencionas:
`t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;`
lo declaras en Start(), y solo se va ejecutar 1 vez.

En segundo lugar, no hay una condición que cuando pasen 10 segundos.

Yo cuando hice algo parecido he hecho lo siguiente:

Atributos: Determinan cada vez que se ha contado un segundo.

`float secondsCounter = 0;
 float secondsToCount = 1;`

Metodo Update:

```
secondsCounter += Time.deltaTime;
 if (secondsCounter >= secondsToCount) {
 secondsToCount = 0;
 number++;
 }
///XX -> Los segundos que quieres que pasen.
if (number == XX) {
/// Lo que tu quieras
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: no bastaría con cambiar de escena después de  t.Stop() ?

Comment: Eso sirve si tu quieres parar el tiempo.  Si haces t.Stop() te sirviria para que si tu pierdes en el juego y deje de contar para los 10 segundos. Cuando pasen 10 segundos en mi método que te he enseñado, deberia de cambiarte el scene. Te recomiendo que pongas `SceneManager.LoadScene("el nombre de tu scene");`